# Combined observable doesn't make HTTP call

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a service with 3 public methods. They depend on result of `this.dossierService.dossierIds`. `dossierIds` is a getter that returns `BehaviorSubject<DossierIds[]>`.

```
 public createObligation(id: string): Observable<void> {
    return this.getObligationsUrl(id).pipe(
      map(dossierIds => {
        const endpoint = `${this.getObligationsUrl(dossierIds)}/blablabla}`;
        return this.http.post(endpoint);
      })
    );
  }


  public deleteMortgageObligation(id: string): Observable<void> {
    return this.getObligationsUrl(id).pipe(
      map(dossierIds => {
        const endpoint = `${this.getObligationsUrl(dossierIds)}/blablabla/${id}`;
        return this.http.delete(endpoint);
      })
    );
  }

  public updateObligation(id: string): Observable<void> {
    //..
  }

  private getObligationsUrl(dossierIds: DossierIds): string {
    return this.dossierService.dossierIds.pipe(
      map(dossierIds => {
        const dossierId = dossierIds.getDossierId();
        const moId = dossierIds.getObligationsId();
        return `${BASE_URL}/${dossierId}/${OBLIGATIONS_URL}/${moId}`;
      }),
    );
  }
```

These methods will be used in a component like this

```
this.createObligation(123).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
})
```

But TypeScript is throwing me an error in all 3 methods saying:

```
Type 'Observable<Observable<void>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<void>'. Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'void'.
```

And I don't even see that my HTTP requests are fired. Where did I make mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason no http call is being made is because you are not subscribing to the inner observable.

```
1   public deleteMortgageObligation(id: string): Observable<void> {
2     return this.getObligationsUrl(id).pipe(
3       map(dossierIds => {
4         const endpoint = `${this.getObligationsUrl(dossierIds)}/blablabla/${id}`;
5         return this.http.delete(endpoint);
6       })
7     );
8   }
```

On line #5, you are returning an observable, but it never gets subscribed to.  Thus line #2 is returning `Observable<Observable<>>`.  You need to ensure this inner observable is subscirbed to and that its result is pushed through the stream.

This is exactly what the "[Higher Order Mapping Operators](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/)" are for.  They do the following:

1. maps the incoming value to another observable
2. subscribes to it, so its values are emitted into the stream
3. manages unsubscribing from these "inner subscriptions"

In your case, we can simply use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) on line #3, instead of `map`:

```
1   public deleteMortgageObligation(id: string): Observable<void> {
2     return this.getObligationsUrl(id).pipe(
3       switchMap(dossierIds => {
4         const endpoint = `${this.getObligationsUrl(dossierIds)}/blablabla/${id}`;
5         return this.http.delete(endpoint);
6       })
7     );
8   }
```